# function based view and error in templates to context the for loop

Tags: django-views

I have an problem when i loop through object_list [image: error]

```
views.py--->

      def product_list(request):
queryset = Product.objects.all()
context = {
    'object_list':queryset
}

return render(request, "products/product_list.html" ,context)
```

**templates**

```
       {% for obj in object_list %}

                {{ obj.title }}


          {% endfor % }
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is  you have an extra space, this

```
  {% endfor % }
```

should be

```
  {% endfor %}
```

keep in mind you will have to rerun django server sometimes to see the affected template files.